# Retrieving the latest entry and then deleting it right away with MongoDB and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Forgive me for my ignorance but  I'm more of a C# developer. This is my first NodeJS program. I'm trying to write a program where my program calls a GET to my node.js server. When the server receives that request I want it to send the latest entry from MongoDB and delete it immediately so it cannot be reused. I want this to be done server-side.

Here's what I have below,

```
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      Todo.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { '_id' : -1 } }, function(err, post) {
        res.json(post);
        Todo.remove({_id: -1});
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the **[`findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove)** API which is an atomic update that issues a mongodb **[`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#dbcmd.findAndModify)** remove command, hence always returns the deleted document. Use the `sort` option to choose which document to delete since multiple docs will be returned by the query:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var query = {},
        options = { "sort": { "_id": -1 } }; // or { "sort": "-_id" } 
    Todo.findOneAndRemove(query, options, function(err, post) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

Comment: MongoError: Cannot specify both new=true and remove=true; 'remove' always returns the deleted document

Comment: My bad, did not have the chance to test